# moeb traverse non-termination

Tags: haskell, recursion

I've recently stumbled upon `loeb` and `moeb` functions [here](https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/loeb-moeb.md) and I'm trying to explore what it can do.

I'm trying to achieve spreadsheet-like behaviour with possibility to perform `IO` in some "cells". I was thinking that `moeb traverse` seemed like good candidate do do this, but any non-trivial (ie. other than `const $ return something`) function in list I used caused the entire call to run forever. After this I tried to test it in `State` monad:

```
moeb f x = fix $ \g -> f ($g) x

foo v = do
    x <- get
    vs <- v
    put (x + 3)
    return (x + (vs!!0))

test = [
    const $ return 7,
    foo,
    fmap length
]

main = print $ runState (moeb traverse test) 5
```

The result was this:

```
([7,12,3],moeb.hs: out of memory
```

Why does this happen? `foo` both gets and sets state, but it evaluates fine, while evaluation of final state hangs.
And how can i achieve spreadsheet-with-IO behavior that terminates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moeb traverse test :: State Int [Int]` is an *action* to produce a list of integers.

If you unfold the definition of `moeb`, you get

```
moeb traverse test
  = traverse ($ moeb traverse test) test
```

meaning that each element f the spreadsheet is passed the *action* `moeb traverse test` to be run, from scratch, instead of using the result of the action recursively.

Generalizing `moeb` using `mfix` might help but I doubt the result will be worth the trouble.

Comment: Ok, i see why it hangs, but what do you mean by generalizing `moeb` using `mfix`?

Comment: A simple one would be `moebM f x = mfix $ \g -> f ($ g) x` . Use `traverse` as the first argument, but `test` will need to change to a different type.